# How to redirect (307 Temporary Redirect) with UrlRewriter?

Tags: urlrewriter.net, urlrewriter, http-status-code-307

i've created a rule using [UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/redirect) to perform a redirect:

```
<rewriter>
   <redirect url="~/ResetClock.ashx" to="~/ResetClock" />
</rewriter>
```

The problem is that it is issuing a `301 Moved Permanantly` redirect:

```
POST /ResetClock.asp HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /ResetClock
```

i can mark the redirect as *"temporary"* redirect:

```
<rewriter>
   <redirect url="~/ResetClock.ashx" to="~/ResetClock" permanent="false" />
</rewriter>
```

In which case it incorrectly issues a `302 Found` redirect:

```
POST /ResetClock.asp HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /ResetClock
```

The problem is that both of these redirects are the wrong redirect to issue. i need UrlRewriter to issue a:

```
307 Temporary Redirect
```

How can i do that?

**Note**: The reason i need it to issue a `307`, is the reason `307` (and `303`) were invented: all browsers handle `302` incorrectly; converting a `POST` into a `GET`. i need to tell the User-Agent that they need to post elsewhere:

```
POST /ResetClock.ashx HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: /ResetClock
```

and the client will issue the redirect to the correct location.